# How to access a web service implemented by ApiController with [Authorize]

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-apicontroller

I am writing a client site C# program, I want to access a web service implemented by ApiController with [Authorize].

the server side code is like:

```
[Authorize]
public class EventsController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("Default")]
    [HttpGet]
    public EventLog[] Get([FromUri]EventsFilter filter)
    {
        return this.HandleExceptions(() => EventService.GetEvents(filter));
    }
}
```

How can I write the client C# code to access it?

Comment: using oath to validate access to your API, this is how ALL api access should be handled, there should be no state management, I.E   cookies with an API,  your client should request a token, and then store this token to validate request with a token / secret handshake.

Comment: There is no straight way to implement it from the box. But you can use some third parties technologies that could make your life easier. Take a look at [OWIN/Katana](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/owin-and-katana) for example

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by using the method in the blog: http://soabubblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/web-api-httpclient-authentication/

> The following helper method is used to login to the service.

```
static class AuthenticationService
{
  public static HttpClient CreateAuthenticatedSession(out HttpStatusCode statusCode)
  {
    var Client = new HttpClient
    {
      BaseAddress = new Uri(@" http://localhost:52310/ ")
    };
 
    var Result = Client.PostAsync("/Account/WebLogOn/",
      new FormUrlEncodedContent(
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
          {"UserName", "test"},
          {"Password", "1234"}
        }
      )
    ).Result;
 
    //Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    statusCode = Result.StatusCode;
 
    return Client;
  }
}
```

> The following client code is to send a request and get the result.

```
void GetProductList()
{
  HttpStatusCode statusCode;
 
  var httpClientSession
    = Helpers.AuthenticationService.CreateAuthenticatedSession(out statusCode);
 
  if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
  {
    httpClientSession.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 
    var result = httpClientSession.GetAsync("/api/product").Result;
 
    // Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
      string responseText = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    else
    {
      string errorText = string.Format("[{0}] - Cannot get the product list.", result.StatusCode);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    string errorText1 = "Authentication Failed";
  }
}
```